# equilateral triangle in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was wondering if there is a way to define an `equilateral triangle` in tikz. I am aware that there is a predefined `isosceles triangle` in `tikz`. Specifically I'd like to define a `\tikzstyle` for `equilateral triangle` and use it in my diagram. The similar situation with `isosceles triangle` is something like

```
\tikzstyle{buffer} = [draw,shape border rotate=-90, isosceles triangle,fill=red, node distance=2cm, minimum height=4em]
```

However, replacing `isosceles` with `equilateral` doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is also the `regular polygon` shape.

(I shamelessly stole and modified Jakes code for this.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
    buffer/.style={
        draw,
        shape border rotate=180,
        regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=3,
        fill=red,
        node distance=2cm,
        minimum height=4em
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[buffer]{Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! This actually makes more sense in this case, since now the label text is placed better, and the corner nodes are called `corner 1`, `corner 2` and `corner 3` instead of `apex`, `right corner` and `left corner`.

Answer (score 20):

You can just set `isosceles triangle apex angle=60` to get an equilateral triangle. The length of the sides is set using `minimum width=<length>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
    buffer/.style={
        draw,
        shape border rotate=-90,
        isosceles triangle,
        isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
        fill=red,
        node distance=2cm,
        minimum height=4em
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}


\node[buffer]{Test};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also the correct answer; however, for the reason you explained , I am gonna go ahead and accept the other one. Hope you don't mind...

Comment: @NNik: Of course not, it's definitely the right thing to do

Comment: As the isosceles triangle does not have to use an incircle, it has a tighter fit for the node text.